# Custom views (Canvas vs. XML)

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-canvas

Based on the posted screenshots, the drawing on the top was created using canvas and the drawing on the bottom was created using XML. The XML drawing is exactly what I want but unfortunately due to Android's 'too many views' warning it's not a good idea for me to use it :-(  As regards to the canvas drawing is there something that I'm missing or not doing right that is causing the drawing to not look exactly like the XML one or do I have to rely on values? I've tried numerous different ways such as changing values of widths and spacing etc. and I STILL had no luck. Even if anyone knows a better method for drawing this, I'd like to know about it please. All relevant advice and help would be appreciated.

**Java (Canvas)**

```
public class Car extends View {
    private final Paint mBlackPaint = new Paint();
    private final Paint mRedPaint = new Paint();
    private final TextPaint mTextPaint;

    public Car(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        int valueInDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        int valueInSp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        mRedPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CC3333"));

        mBlackPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
        mBlackPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mBlackPaint.setStrokeWidth(valueInDp);
        mBlackPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        mTextPaint = new TextPaint(TextPaint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mTextPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mTextPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(valueInSp);

        mWindowPaint = new Paint();
        mWindowPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#CC3333"));
        mWindowPaint.setStrokeWidth(valueInDp);
    }

    private Paint mWindowPaint;
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    Rect rect2 = new Rect();

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (getWidth() == 0)
            return;

        int w = canvas.getWidth();
        int h = canvas.getHeight();

        int rectWidth = ((w - 20) / 4) / 6;
        int space = (((w - 20) / 4) / 13);
        int oneSevenSpace = (((w - 20) / 4) / 6);
        int oneSevenWidth = ((w - 20) / 4) / 6;
        int topRectHeight = getPaddingTop();
        int bottomRectHeight = getPaddingBottom();


        //draw red rectangles
        int mSideRectWidth = 10;
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, mSideRectWidth, getHeight(), mRedPaint); //draw left end rectangle
        canvas.drawRect(getWidth() - mSideRectWidth, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), mRedPaint); //draw right end rectangle

        //draw carriages
        setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
        int boxWidth = (getWidth() - mSideRectWidth) / 4;

        //draw text views
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(i + 1), (i * boxWidth + 10) + (boxWidth / 2), ((canvas.getHeight() / 2) - ((mTextPaint.descent() + mTextPaint.ascent()) / 2)), mTextPaint);
        }

        //draw box separators
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
            canvas.drawLine(mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, 0, mSideRectWidth + boxWidth * i, getHeight(), mBlackPaint);
        }

        //draw windows
        for (int index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
            if (index == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    mWindowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                    int left = ((i * (oneSevenWidth + oneSevenSpace)) + 6) + (index * boxWidth) + 15 + (oneSevenSpace / 2);
                    int right = left + oneSevenWidth;

                    rect.set(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
                    canvas.drawRect(rect, mWindowPaint);

                    rect2.set(left, h - bottomRectHeight, right, h);
                    canvas.drawRect(rect2, mWindowPaint);
                }
            }
            if (index == 1 || index == 2) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                    mWindowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                    int left = ((i * (rectWidth + space))) + (index * boxWidth) + 15 + (space / 2);
                    int right = left + rectWidth;

                    rect2.set(left, h - bottomRectHeight, right, h);
                    canvas.drawRect(rect2, mWindowPaint);

                    if (index == 2 && i == 3) {
                        mWindowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
                    }
                    rect.set(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
                    canvas.drawRect(rect, mWindowPaint);
                }
            }
            if (index == 3) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    mWindowPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                    int left = ((i * (oneSevenWidth + oneSevenSpace)) - 1) + ((index * boxWidth)) + (space * 2);
                    int right = left + oneSevenWidth;

                    rect.set(left, 0, right, topRectHeight);
                    canvas.drawRect(rect, mWindowPaint);

                    rect2.set(left, h - bottomRectHeight, right, h);
                    canvas.drawRect(rect2, mWindowPaint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CC3333" />

<!--start of carriage 1-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#808080" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="4" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--end of carriage 1-->

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1D1D1D" />

<!--start of carriage 2-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#808080" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--end of carriage 2-->

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1D1D1D" />

<!--start of carriage 3-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#808080" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="3"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/fullrect_red" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="6" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="7" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--end of carriage 3-->

<View
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#1D1D1D" />

<!--start of carriage 4-->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#808080" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:background="@drawable/emptyrect_red" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="18" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
<!--end of box 4-->

<View
    android:layout_width="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#CC3333" />
```

**Results**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use floats rather than ints for your layout calculations, then cast to an int whenever the Android framework requires it.

```
int rectWidth = ((w - 20) / 4) / 6;
```

For example, the value of rectWidth here will be truncated to the nearest integer. The loss of precision is compounded in later calculations, leading to the different behaviour.

Comment: You need to cast any int parameters to a float e.g. where n is an integer `(float) n`